# VBscript for Excel to count strings within a column

Tags: excel, vbscript

Each month I receive about 300 Excel files. I need to get a count of column C from a certain sheet within each file. I tried VBA but I am unable to embed a macro into each file (due to logistics and security at each location). I also tried a 'summary' file with links to each file but the links became unstable and I couldn't trust the numbers I was getting. So I thought about a vbscript.

There are only certain codes I'm looking to count: XF, RE, AG, and LK. I don't care about what else is in the column or if there are blanks.

The name of the column is 'Codes' (not sure if that makes a difference)

The name of the sheet I'm interested in is 'Ticket Source'. There are several other sheets in the workbook.

I'd like to have the counts end up in a file (either TXT or CSV) that includes the file name, the code, and the count for that code.

Example:

```
Filename: NORTHWEST
XF - 260
RE - 120
AG - 320
LK - 250
```

The file names are anything and everything so I'll have to create a batch file to run against the name of the file. The version of Excel I'm using is 2010.

I have no clue how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You had the better approach and prefer a worst one against correcting "links became unstable"??? Each call to VBScript will create a new Excel instance... Using 'summary' file will be much faster and effective...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True  'set to False for production

Set outfile = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True)

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Ticket Source")

    xf = 0
    re = 0

    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(23).Cells
      Select Case cell.Value
        Case "XF" : xf = xf + 1
        Case "RE" : re = re + 1
      End Select
    Next

    outfile.WriteLine "Filename: " & f.Name _
      & vbNewline & "XF - " & xf _
      & vbNewLine & "RE - " & re

    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close
  End If
Next

outfile.Close
xl.Quit
```

Of course you'll need to adjust column number and output filename to your needs.

Comment: Where came `ws.UsedRange.Columns(23).Cells` from? Agree with everything but that.

Comment: On some of the files it's asking "Do you want to save changes to the file?"  Is there a way to suppress that message or tell it NOT to save the file? Otherwise, seems to be working as advertised.

Comment: @LS_dev 23 is just a random number I picked as an example, so it needs to be replaced with the correct column number as mentioned at the end of my answer. The whole statement returns the cells of a specific column of the range of used cells in the worksheet.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas If you never want to save the workbooks you can set the `Saved` property to `True` before closing it. See updated answer. Note that this will discard all changes to a workbook.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, didn't read last line. However, should use `Intersect(ws.Columns("C"), ws.UsedRange).Cells` because you can't guarantee that `UsedRange` begins at column A. Also `wb.Close False` eliminates need for `wb.Saved = True` line.

Comment: @LS_dev `UsedRange.Columns(n)` returns the nth column of the used range, not the nth column of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

vbscript that will get the counts by using Countif instead of looking at each cell individually:

```
Dim oShell
Dim oFSO
Dim oOutput
Dim oFile
Dim xlApp
Dim strFolderPath
Dim Code

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
On Error Resume Next
strFolderPath = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Folder", 0).Self.Path
On Error GoTo 0

If Len(strFolderPath) > 0 Then
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oOutput = oFSO.CreateTextFile(oShell.NameSpace(&h10).Self.Path & "\Code Counts.txt", True)  'Puts the output file on your desktop
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    For Each oFile in oFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath).Files
        If LCase(Left(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile), 3)) = "xls" Then
            With xlApp.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
                If xlApp.Evaluate("ISREF('Ticket Source'!A1)") = True Then
                    oOutput.WriteLine "Filename: " & oFile.Name
                    For Each Code in Array("XF", "RE", "AG", "LK")
                        oOutput.WriteLine Code & " - " & xlApp.Evaluate("COUNTIF('Ticket Source'!C:C,""" & Code & """)")
                    Next
                End If
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next

    xlApp.Quit
    oOutput.Close

    MsgBox "Code Counts Completed"

End If

Set oShell = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oOutput = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```